# how to get time of execution in rundeck and use it in another job?

Tags: rundeck

I've been searching does rundeck supports jobs dependencies?

That's what I found [Does rundeck support jobs dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291321/does-rundeck-supports-jobs-dependencies?rq=1)
so I need to get the time of execution of job-1 in rundeck and use it in another job-2 to run it with a  cron after the time of execution of job-1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does rundeck supports jobs dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291321/does-rundeck-supports-jobs-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is using 'time' command on your steps and use it on some global option (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/configuration-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables): [How do I get just real time value from 'time' command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795470/how-do-i-get-just-real-time-value-from-time-command)

Also, you can use Execution Data vars for use it on a notification. Check it: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/notification-plugin.html#execution-data you can play with ${execution.dateStarted} and ${execution.dateEnded}

Comment: thank you for reply 
${execution.dateEnded} can i use it without plugin   ?

Comment: I'm sorry, the execution is for notification plugins, but you can use the time command, I modified the answer.